# Declarative dynamic bundling/minification for MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification, squishit

Is there a stock or pluggable way (like a NuGet package) to let me declare `.js`, `.css`, and ideally `.less` files in the MVC views and partials where I use them, and have them automatically runtime bundle and minify in production? (a.k.a. "[Autobunding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239603/did-auto-bundling-minification-get-tossed-in-final-release-of-mvc-4)")

I've tried the built-in MVC 4 bundling. I dislike that bundles are defined far away from where a page author would expect to find them, in `BundleConfig.cs` . This is unworkable for non-C# team members.

As **an example of what I'm looking for**, here's what I cobbled together myself using [SquishIt](https://github.com/jetheredge/SquishIt).

**ExtendedViewPage.cs**

```
/// <summary>
/// Caches a bundle of .js and/or .css specific to this ViewPage, at a path similar to:
/// shared_signinpartial_F3BD3CCE1DFCEA70F5524C57164EB48E.js
/// </summary>
public abstract class ExtendedViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel> {
    // This is where I keep my assets, and since I don't actually store any in my root,
    // I emit all my bundles here. I also use the the web deployment engine,
    // and remove extra files on publish, so I never personally have to clean them up,
    // and I also don't have to hand-identify generated bundles from original code.
    // However, to keep from needing to give the app write permissions
    // on a static content folder, or collocate bundles with original assets,
    // or conform to a specific asset path, this should surely be configurable
    private const string ASSET_PATH = "~/assets/";

    /// <summary>
    /// Emits here the bundled resources declared with "AddResources" on all child controls
    /// </summary>
    public MvcHtmlString ResourceLinks {
        get {
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(
                string.Join("", CssResourceLinks) + string.Join("", JsResourceLinks));
        }
    }

    // This allows all resources to be specified in a single command,
    // which permits .css and .js resources to be declared in an
    // interwoven manner, in any order the site author prefers
    // For me, this makes it clearer, to group my related .css and .js links,
    // and to place my often control-specific CSS near last in the list
    /// <summary>
    /// Queues compressible resources to be emitted with the ResourceLinks directive
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="resourceFiles">Project paths to JavaScript and/or CSS files</param>
    public void AddResources(params string[] resourceFiles) {
        var css = FilterFileExtension(resourceFiles, ".css");
        AddCssResources(css);
        var js = FilterFileExtension(resourceFiles, ".js");
        AddJsResources(js);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Bundles JavaScript files to be emitted with the ResourceLinks directive
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="resourceFiles">Zero or more project paths to JavaScript files</param>
    public void AddJsResources(params string[] resourceFiles) {
        if (resourceFiles.Any()) {
            JavaScriptBundle jsBundle = Bundle.JavaScript();
            foreach (string jsFile in resourceFiles) {
                jsBundle.Add(jsFile);
            }
            // Pages render from the inside-out, which is required for us to expose
            // our resources declared in children to the parent where they are emitted
            // however, it also means our resources naturally collect here in an order
            // that is probably not what the site author intends.
            // We reverse the order with insert
            JsResourceLinks.Insert(0, jsBundle.MvcRender(ASSET_PATH + ViewIdentifier + "_#.js"));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Bundles CSS files to be emitted with the ResourceLinks directive
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="resourceFiles">Zero or more project paths to CSS files</param>
    public void AddCssResources(params string[] resourceFiles) {
        // Create a separate reference for each CSS path, since CSS files typically include path-relative images.
        foreach (
            var cssFolder in resourceFiles.
                GroupBy(r => r.Substring(0, r.LastIndexOf('/')).ToLowerInvariant()).
                // Note the CssResourceLinks.Insert command below reverses not only desirably
                // the order of view emission, but also undesirably reverses the order of resources within this one view.
                // for this page we'll 'pre-reverse' them. There's probably a clearer way to address this.
                Reverse()) {
            CSSBundle cssBundle = Bundle.Css();
            foreach (string cssFile in cssFolder) {
                cssBundle.Add(cssFile);
            }
            // See JsResourceLinks.Insert comment above
            CssResourceLinks.Insert(0, cssBundle.MvcRender(cssFolder.Key + "/" + ViewIdentifier + "_#.css"));
        }
    }

    #region private implementation
    private string _viewIdentifier = null;
    // ViewIdentifier returns a site-unique name for the current control, such as "shared_signinpartial"
    // Some security wonks may take issue with exposing folder structure here
    // It may be appropriate to obfuscate it with a checksum
    private string ViewIdentifier {
        get {
            if (_viewIdentifier == null) {
                _viewIdentifier =
                    // VirtualPath uniquely identifies the currently rendering View or Partial,
                    // such as "~/Views/Shared/SignInPartial.cshtml"
                    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(VirtualPath).
                    // This "Substring" truncates the ~/Views/ or ~/Areas/ in my build, in others
                    // but it is probably inappropriate to make this assumption.
                    // It is certainly possible to have views in the root.
                    // Substring(8).
                    // It's assumed all of these bundles will be output to a single folder,
                    // to keep filesystem write-access minimal, so we flatten them here.
                    Replace("/", "_").
                    // The following assumes a typical MS filesystem, preserve-but-ignore case.
                    // The .NET string recommendations suggest instead using ToUpperInvariant
                    // for such an operation, but this was just a personal preference.
                    // My IIS rules typically drop the case on all content served.
                    // It may be altogether inappropriate to alter,
                    // although appending the MD5 hash ensure it does no harm on other platforms,
                    // while still collapsing the cases where multiply-cased aliases are used
                    ToLowerInvariant();
            }
            return _viewIdentifier;
        }
    }

    private List<MvcHtmlString> CssResourceLinks {
        get { return getContextHtmlStringList("SquishItCssResourceLinks"); }
    }

    private List<MvcHtmlString> JsResourceLinks {
        get { return getContextHtmlStringList("SquishItJsResourceLinks"); }
    }

    // Note that at the resource render, if no bundles of a specific type (.css or .js)
    // have been provided, this performs the unnecessary operation of instanciating a new List<MvcHtmlString>
    // and adding it to the HttpContext.Items. This get/set could benefit from some clarification.
    private List<MvcHtmlString> getContextHtmlStringList(string itemName) {
        IDictionary contextItems = Context.ApplicationInstance.Context.Items;
        List<MvcHtmlString> resourceLinks;
        if (contextItems.Contains(itemName)) {
            resourceLinks = contextItems[itemName] as List<MvcHtmlString>;
        }
        else {
            resourceLinks = new List<MvcHtmlString>();
            contextItems.Add(itemName, resourceLinks);
        }
        return resourceLinks;
    }

    private string[] FilterFileExtension(string[] filenames, string mustEndWith) {
        IEnumerable<string> filtered =
            filenames.Where(r => r.EndsWith(mustEndWith, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        return filtered.ToArray();
    }
    #endregion private implementation
}
```

**PageWithHeaderLayout.cshtml** (example usage)

```
@{
    AddResources(
        Links.Assets.Common.Script.GoogleAnalytics_js,
        Links.Assets.Common.Style.ProprietaryTheme.jquery_ui_1_8_23_custom_css,
        Links.Assets.Common.Style.SiteStandards_css,
        Links.Assets.Common.CdnMirror.jquery._1_7_2.jquery_js,
        Links.Assets.Common.CdnMirror.jQuery_Validate._2_0_0pre.jquery_validate_120826_js,
        Links.Assets.Common.CdnMirror.jqueryui._1_8_23.jquery_ui_min_js,
        Links.Assets.Common.JqueryPlugins.templates.jquery_tmpl_min_js,
        Links.Assets.Common.JqueryPlugins.jquery_ajaxmanager_js,
        Links.Assets.Common.JqueryPlugins.hashchange.jquery_ba_hashchange_min_js
        );
}

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <meta name="description" content="@ViewBag.Description" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="@ViewBag.Keywords" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="@Url.Content("~/favicon.ico")" type="image/x-icon" />
    <!-- all bundles from all page components are emitted here -->
    @ResourceLinks
</head>
<body>
    @Html.Partial(MVC.Common.Views.ContextNavigationTree)
    <div id="pageContent">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately I wrote it, so it has many limitations. Scripts don't de-duplicate, it takes a simple approach to bundle delineation, I added an ugly hack recently to permit `.less` support, etc.

Are there any existing solutions to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a comment but I ran out of space.

This is neat but it seems like you end up with one bundle per (complete, rendered) page, which is pretty much the worst case scenario for a first-time visitor to the site.  If you have several pages that use the same master page and don't add any additional content, you will end up with the same large file downloaded on each page with a different name.  Instead of basing the name off the page name, try concatenating all of the filenames (in order) and calculating an MD5 hash to use as your bundle name - this serves as a fairly good uniqueness check, and should really cut down on your bandwidth usage.  You can see an example [here](https://github.com/jetheredge/SquishIt/blob/master/SquishIt.Framework/Base/BundleBase.Rendering.Internals.cs#L189-193) of how we do this in SquishIt - just remember that the value you calculated would be whats coming in as "key" at this point in the code.  Another thing I would consider is defining bundles **per physical view file** instead of for the entire page, to maximize reusability.

I realize this sounds critical, but I do like the general direction you're going with this.  I'm just not sure what the exact destination is.  If you need any help, I try to watch this tag pretty closely and I'm pretty easy to find elsewhere.

As far as "auto-bundling" is concerned, I don't think there is anything out there that does what you're looking for - in large part because it requires such a nuanced approach.  You can look at [RequestReduce](http://requestreduce.org/) - it does a lot of optimization for you without intervention, but I don't believe it combines assets.

Comment: Actually the bundles are generated per component. If there is no unique javascript or css on a page (which occurs for most public content) there is no bundle generated. Still, I know my code has drawbacks, which is why I'm looking for code someone else wrote :).

Comment: That said, if nothing exists, then I'd be willing to invest a little time to push this idea into the community.

Comment: LOL, I didn't even realize it was you Alex. :) Thanks for your help a  few months back. I sent this code to you back then when you asked out of curiosity why I was running into null checks on something.

Comment: Also, note that the bundle IDs are indeed using an MD5 hash as you suggest, since it's coming from SquishIt. :)

Comment: Oh shoot cant believe i forgot that :)  I thought virtual path would return the path to the page not the control. Any reason you add the resources all together instead of in separate script and style buckets? Would make preprocessing a lot easier.  Exposing separately could help when you want scripts to render later in page.  I actually usually end up maintaining a third for scripts that need to be in the head.  It would be really cool to include this kind of thing in squishit.MVC with a control equivalent. Would need a way to control rendering strategy (in memory vs file etc).

Comment: The reason I chose to declare the bundle together is not of much consequence. This way allows the author to preserve whatever declaration order they would have had previously. I personally like to keep my page-specific .css and .js references together at the very end of the list, because it makes it convenient for me to scan visually for local docs. That coupled with a little macro I wrote and I can F12-go-to-definition to open my local script and style resources to edit. Just a personal workflow thing.

Comment: I suppose they should probably be broken out for clarity regardless, and then if the single-declaration method is implemented it's just a small LINQ wrapper around the other methods. I always assumed I would find a product to replace my little shim in the near future.

Comment: Also note the crucial part that simplifies the process is that controls render from the innermost out (as I'm sure you've dealt with), which allows the render code here to be quite sparse.

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look at the [Enfold project](https://github.com/achingono/Enfold). It might be the solution that you are looking for.

Assuming you have the following views in the web project:

> ~/Views/Home/About.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Home/Contact.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml

You can organize your Javascript files this way:

> ~/Scripts/Views/default.js
>   ~/Scripts/Views/Home/default.js
>   ~/Scripts/Views/Home/about.js
>   ~/Scripts/Views/Home/contact.js
>   ~/Scripts/Views/Home/index.js

With such a setup, the following bundles will be created:

> **~/bundles/home/about**
>
> > ~/scripts/views/default.js
> >     ~/scripts/views/home/default.js
> >     ~/scripts/views/home/about.js
>
> **~/bundles/home/contact**
>
> > ~/scripts/views/default.js
> >     ~/scripts/views/home/default.js
> >     ~/scripts/views/home/contact.js
>
> **~/bundles/home/index**
>
> > ~/scripts/views/default.js
> >     ~/scripts/views/home/default.js
> >     ~/scripts/views/home/index.js

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Fixed, does that help?